# If $(A) ∪ (B) = (A ∪ B)$ then $A ⊆ B$ or $B ⊆ A$. Help needed.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I was trying to prove the following:

For any sets $A$ and $B$, if $(A) ∪ (B) = (A ∪ B)$ then $A ⊆ B$ or $B ⊆ A$.

My proof: Let $A$ and $B$ be arbitrary sets. Suppose $(A) ∪ (B) = (A ∪ B)$. Assume, by way of contradiction, that $(¬(A ⊆ B) ∧ ¬(B ⊆ A))$. Then there are elements $y$ and $x$, such that $x ∈ A ∧ x ∉ B$ and $y ∈ B ∧ y ∉ A$. Notice $x ∈ A ∪ B$, and $y ∈ A ∪ B$. Let $W = \lbrace x,y \rbrace$. Then $W ⊆ A ∪ B$. So $W ∈ (A ∪ B)$. Hence $W ∈ (A) ∪ (B)$. Assume $W ∈ (A)$. Then $W ⊆ A$, so $x,y ∈ A$. But $y ∉ A$, so $W ∉ (A)$. Then $W ∈ (B)$, but then $x,y ∈ B$, in particular $x ∈ B$. But that's a contradiction, so $W ∉ (b)$. Thus, we have $W ∈ (A) ∪ (B)$ and $W ∉ (A)$ and $W ∉ (B)$. Therefore, our assumption that $(¬(A ⊆ B) ∧ ¬(B ⊆ A))$ must be wrong. Ergo, $A ⊆ B$ or $B ⊆ A$.

I am suspicious of the step where I create a set $W = \lbrace x,y\rbrace$. It seems a bit odd, to be able to create a set out of the blue, especially since $W$ is not arbitrary, it includes $x$ and $y$. While I can see that $x$ and $y$ must exist, I don't see why they must be in the same set.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: "*While I can see that $x$ and $y$ must exist, I don't see why they must be in the same set*"  If you accept the existence of $x$, then you should also accept the existence of $\{x\}$.  Similarly you should also accept the existence of $\{y\}$... and then should accept the existence of $\{x\}\cup \{y\}$.  See the [Axiom of Pairing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_pairing).

Comment: @JMoravitz, Could you elaborate on how the existence of {x} follows from x? We can have 3 in a set, and not {3}. Furtheremore, how does the existence of  {}∪{} follow from existence of {x}?

Comment: The existence of $\{x\}$ following from the existence of $x$ is also a result of the Axiom of Pairing... here by taking both $A$ and $B$ to be $x$ itself.  These explanations of course assume you are working in a set theory with this as an axiom such as in ZFC.  If you are working in a different set theory then you should say so.  $A\cup B$ existing given sets $A$ and $B$ follows from the [axiom of union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory#5._Axiom_of_union) and axiom of pairing.

Comment: @JMoravitz, reading the definition of Axiom of Pairing, this is more clear now. I wasn't aware of the axioms, since this proof is part of an elementary proof writing class, and we have not covered many of the axioms of set theory yet.

Comment: You really shouldn't be so worried about $W$ - you're just defining $W$ to be a set containing some elements. That's allowed, in the same way as "let $X = \{1, 2, 3\}$" is allowed. I think your proof looks fine - you seem to have paid a lot of attention to detail. Perhaps this is the point of your proof-writing class, but personally I dislike symbols like $\land$ or $\lnot$ in written mathematics (they don't really make anything any clearer!). It can also be interesting to see if you can "unwrap" the contradiction structure of the argument - in this case, you could argue more directly..

Comment: Namely, since $\mathscr P(A \cup B) = \mathscr P(A) \cup \mathscr P(B)$, we have $A \cup B \in  \mathscr P(A) \cup \mathscr P(B)$. So either $A \cup B$ belongs to $ \mathscr P(A)$ or $\mathscr P(B)$. If it belongs to $\mathscr P(A)$, then $A \cup B \subseteq A$, and therefore we have $B \subseteq A$. Similarly, if it belonged to $\mathscr P(B)$, then we have $A \subseteq B$.